text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis; not working with my subgrid
I had trouble implementing my layout with a table, so I used a subgrid instead (which I found worked much better). Here's what that looks like right now:

Basically it's supposed to display names and comments in a simple table that fit on one line without overflowing. As you can tell, the texts are too long for that right now. Either they word break on a new line and make the blue rows more than one line, or cause it to overflow.
Here's the code so far:


html {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 600px;
  min-width: 800px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
}

.g {
  background-color: green;
}

.r {
  background-color: red;
}

.y {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.m {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.w {
  background-color: white;
}

.p {
  background-color: pink;
}

.l {
  background-color: lime;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <div class="flex-grow-1 b d-flex flex-column gap-3">
    <div>asfdsa</div>
    <div className="m">

      <!-- Table Container -->
      <div class="justify-content-center overflow-hidden g flex-grow-1  m-1" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr; grid-auto-flow: row ">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="border-bottom r border-2" style="display: grid; grid-column: 1 / -1; grid-template-columns: subgrid ">
          <div class="border-start p-2 l">Username</div>
          <div class="border-start p-2 p">Message</div>
          <div class="border-start p-2 w">Comment</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Data Row 1-->
        <div class="bg-info m-2 p-2 rounded" style="display: grid; grid-column: 1 / -1; grid-template-columns: subgrid">
          <div className="border-start p-2 l">Jack Brown</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 p">It's done.</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 w">That's good dear. Did you also remember to bring the lorem ipsum? It's on sale tonight. K thx love u</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Data Row 2-->
        <div class="bg-info m-2 p-2 rounded" style="display: grid; grid-column: 1 / -1; grid-template-columns: subgrid">
          <div className="border-start p-2 l">Alastair Percival Montague-Fitzherbert St. John-Reginald Archibald Crispin Harcourt</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 p">Oi Mate</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 w">value</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Data Row 3-->
        <div class="bg-info m-2 p-2 rounded" style="display: grid; grid-column: 1 / -1; grid-template-columns: subgrid">
          <div className="border-start p-2 l">Lin Dong</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 p">Heeeeeelp my eeeeeeee keeeeeeeey is brokeeeeeeeeeeen eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
          <div className="border-start p-2 w">K.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>



Here's what I would like it to actually look like

I tried using
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden

And it doesn't work, using an actual table also does nothing. How can I properly clip the text so it cannot overflow the table?

add white-space: nowrap;min-width:0

it is also missing text-overflow .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow
